# Insert data list from one table to another table asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, model

I basically want to insert a data list from one table to another. I want the current list from the "**Teacher**" table to be inserted into the "**Attendance**" table as a list.  The below code is the one that I tried to use and it's not working. Remember I don't add any row, but just insert the data as the way it is listed.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e, Teacher[] teacher)
    {
        var status = false;
        using (ApplicationDbContext dc = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            if (e.EventID > 0)
            {
                //Update the event
                var v = dc.events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    v.Subject = e.Subject;
                    v.Start = e.Start;
                    v.End = e.End;
                    v.Description = e.Description;
                    v.Course = e.Description;
                    v.IsFullDay = e.IsFullDay;
                    v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
                }
            }
            else
            {


                foreach (var item in teacher)
                {
                    Attendance att = new Attendance();
                    att.TeacherId = item.TeacherId;
                    att.Firstname = item.Firstname;
                    att.Lastname = item.Lastname;
                    att.IdNumber = item.IdNumber;
                    att.Course = item.Course;
                    //att.Date = v.Start;

                    dc.attendances.Add(att);
                }

                dc.events.Add(e);
            }

            dc.SaveChanges();
            status = true;

        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
```

Comment: Does it ever get into the `else`?

Comment: Yes it triggers to say error: the "teacher" is null

Comment: Well then surely that's why nothing is being inserted into the database?

Comment: But then the "teacher" table has data already and I don't want to add more, is it possible?

Comment: **/Update the event** I have not seen the statement update to db like `db.Entry(v).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` . Besides, You should make sure that `teacher` has value by debugging to check it.